# pi_face_tracker problem

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
i have installed your package. i am trying to use it ,but i haven't succeeded.
firstly i run cheese because without it nothing works. then i run the two commands .
from the first one
i get a : [ WARN] [1377289686.323464310]: Reconfigure callback failed with exception unable to allocate buffers.
the other one works fine . so i get a  : [INFO] [WallTime: 1377289898.645841] Starting pi_face_tracker.

the problem is that when i type
rostopic echo /whatever gets published
then nothing appears on my screen, not even my
/camera/image_raw.

the cheese program works fine .
what should i do

edit: i just saw the with my laptops camera it works fine. with my msi star cam clip it does not.
and when i run the first command i get

```
: Invalid argument
[ERROR] [1377291803.163531318]: Problem setting exposure. Exception was unable to get control

setting control 9a0902
unable to get control
: Invalid argument
[ERROR] [1377291803.163756417]: Problem setting absolute exposure. Exception was unable to get control

setting control 98091b
current value of 98091b is 90
new value of 98091b is 142
setting control 98090c
unable to get control
: Invalid argument
[ERROR] [1377291803.164985903]: Problem setting white balance temperature. Exception was unable to get control

setting control 980913
unable to get control
: Invalid argument
[ERROR] [1377291803.165156665]: Problem setting gain. Exception was unable to get control

setting control 980902
current value of 980902 is 25
unable to set control
: Numerical result out of range
[ERROR] [1377291803.165319116]: Problem setting saturation. Exception was unable to set control

setting control 980901
current value of 980901 is 20
new value of 980901 is 50
setting control 980900
current value of 980900 is 128
new value of 980900 is 66
Segmentation fault, stopping uvc camera driver.
[ERROR] [1377291803.302588952]: Segmentation fault, stopping uvc camera driver.
[uvc_cam_node-2] process has died [pid 15237, exit code -11, cmd /home/alexandros/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/uvc_cam/bin/uvc_cam_node __name:=uvc_cam_node __log:=/home/alexandros/.ros/log/71731024-0c37-11e3-a02f-001de0d62475/uvc_cam_node-2.log].
log file: /home/alexandros/.ros/log/71731024-0c37-11e3-a02f-001de0d62475/uvc_cam_node-2*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74578/pi_face_tracker-problem/) by [rem870](https://answers.ros.org/users/5383/rem870/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2013-08-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since the pi_face_tracker package works with your laptop camera, it sounds like your msi star cam clip is not supported by the uvc_cam driver.  You might try the [camera_umd](http://ros.org/wiki/camera_umd) driver instead as follows.  I see you are using ROS Fuerte so you can install the camera_umd package using the commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-camera-umd
$ rospack profile
```

I have added a suitable launch file for this driver to the pi_face_tracker package.  To get the update run the commands:

```
$ roscd pi_vision
$ svn update
$ rospack profile
```

You can now try this launch file with your msi camera which is probably /dev/video1 on your laptop.  Assuming the camera is plugged in to a USB port, run the command:

```
$ roslaunch pi_face_tracker camera_node.launch device:=/dev/video1
```

Then test to see if you have an image by running the command:

```
$ rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/image_raw
```

If you do not see an image, it is possible you camera is not uvc-compatible.  If you do see an image, you can try pi_face_tracker.  Ctrl-C out of the image_view process then run:

```
$ roslaunch pi_face_tracker face_tracker_uvc_cam.launch
```

--patrick

http://www.pirobot.org

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2013-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rem870](https://answers.ros.org/users/5383/rem870/) on 2013-08-25**:
hi
thanks for the answer,
it worked half way,
i get an image from my web cam but it just 'green' noise.
so my camera is not uvc?

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2013-08-25**:
It sounds like that might be true but I am not a Linux video expert.  I've had good luck with Logitech cameras and a Philips camera but have not tried other brands.

**Comment by [rem870](https://answers.ros.org/users/5383/rem870/) on 2013-08-25**:
ok , in 3-4 days i will be able to test it with a kinect
and i hope that it will be able to give me the exact location (xyz) of the face
via the /target_point .